# ProducerTemplate null when used to construct bean in new JndiContext in a unit test

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-camel

ProducerTemplate null when used to construct bean in new JndiContext in a unit test

I am trying to unit test a route that uses bean to dynamically construct an sftp endpoint. This works when I run my route in a normal context, as it seems a template is already in the registry and can be correctly injected.

My problem is when trying to construct the unit test I seem to be running into a condition where the ProducerTemplate is still null when `createJndiContext` is invoked and that results in an NPE in my bean that need to call a method on the template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a simplified unit test that illustrates this:

```
public class BeanWithProdTemplateDependencyTest
  extends CamelTestSupport
{

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BeanWithProdTemplateDependencyTest.class);
  private static final String FROM = "direct:start";

  @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
  protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {

    super.setUp();
    context.getRouteDefinition("my-cool-route").adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder()
    {

      @Override
      public void configure()
        throws Exception
      {
        replaceFromWith(FROM);

      }
    });
    startCamelContext();

  }

  @Test
  public void test()
  {
    template.sendBody(FROM, "cheese");
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isUseAdviceWith()
  {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  protected Context createJndiContext()
    throws Exception
  {
    JndiContext context = new JndiContext();
    MyBean myBean = new MyBean(template);
    context.bind("myBean", myBean);

    return context;
  }

  @Override
  protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder()
    throws Exception
  {
    return new RouteBuilder()
    {

      @Override
      public void configure()
        throws Exception
      {
        from("jms:queue:inbox")
        .routeId("my-cool-route")
        .beanRef("myBean", "doStuff")
        .log("Body: $body}")
        .to("mock:result");
      }
    };
  }

  public class MyBean {

    private final ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    public MyBean(ProducerTemplate template)
    {
      this.producerTemplate = template;
    }

    public void doStuff() throws Exception{
      // NPE here, template is null
      this.producerTemplate.sendBody("seda:foo", "beer");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In looking at the [CamelTestSupport](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.camel/camel-test/2.13.2/org/apache/camel/test/junit4/CamelTestSupport.java#CamelTestSupport.doSetUp%28%29) code, I can see how this is happening as the operation creating the Camel Context also spawns the bean JndiRegistry and all that happens before the template is created. So how do I short circuit this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the work-around with a little [help from here](http://alwaysthinkingaboutcode.blogspot.com/2013/03/camel-testing-adding-custom-beans-to.html).

I was trying to do too much too soon. I eliminated the override of `createJndiContext()` and added these line to the `setUp()` method in my test:

```
MyBean myBean = new MyBean(template);

JndiRegistry registry = (JndiRegistry) (
    (PropertyPlaceholderDelegateRegistry)context.getRegistry()).getRegistry();
registry.bind("myBean", myBean);
```

This allowed me to create my bean with a non-null ProducerTemplate and push it into the Registry created by `CamelTestSupport.setUp()`